# What is the best way to insert rows to a database using the primary key in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

Sorry for my vague-ish title. Basically, I have a Call Logging app that uses a database with 2 tables (Customer and Records) to add, remove and search for records. I have a column in Records called 'CallID' that I use to help keep the calls unique and so I can use the CallID to Remove specific records. However, the problem lies on my adding call function. I currently have it so that the CallID is the number of items in the list incremented by 1:

```
private void addcall_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            //This is my addcall click event that inserts a row in 'Records' table using what the user has entered into the fields
            string sql = "INSERT Records (CustomerID, CallID, CustomerName, Telephone, DateAndTime, Status, Description) VALUES (@CustomerID, @CallID, @CustomerName, @Telephone, @DateAndTime, @Status, @Description)";
            SqlConnection conn = ConnectionString();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CustomerID", customerID_cb.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CallID", (CallListBox.Items.Count + 1));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DateAndTime", DateTime.Now);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Status", status_cb.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Description", description_txt.Text);
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Record Created");
            this.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

You probably know by now that simply incrementing one to the number of items in the list is a clumsy way of doing things and it leads to problems after records have been removed and you want to add more. I want to know if there is a way to do what I am trying to do but in a much better way :)

Thanks!

Comment: What is CallListBox in you code ?. Which items are binded in CallListBox ?

Comment: Can't you just make CallID an auto increment field in the database?

Comment: CallListBox is the name of my listbox on my windows form. The items in the listbox are the existing rows in the Records table, I will clarify some things in an edit to my question.

Comment: GO ahead. But i got your point of question.(+1 for good question). You may try with Max() in sql right instead of binding entire things into ListBox?

Comment: Hmm auto incrementation sounds ideal. Unfortunately I am new to sql server. How would I set the column to be auto incremented?

Comment: Ok so it seems auto incrementation is the exact solution I was looking for. Works like a charm now! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `CallID` to auto increment

```
ALTER TABLE Records AUTO_INCREMENT=1
```

Then change your insert statement so that it excludes the field

```
INSERT Records (CustomerID, CustomerName, Telephone, DateAndTime, Status, Description) VALUES (@CustomerID, @CustomerName, @Telephone, @DateAndTime, @Status, @Description)
```

The value for the `CallID` field will then be handled by the database for any subsequent rows added.

Answer (score 1):

Proceed in this way(Incase if you're not using auto increment in database), it may help you.

Bind your last value into label or textbox,

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String");
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Max(CallID) from Yourtablename",con);    
SQlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while(dr.Read())
{
    Label1.Text = dr.GetInt32(0).ToString();
}
con.Close();
```

Change like this in your above code,

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CallID", Convert.ToInt32(Label1.Text));
```

Make a datatype to int of your CallID column.

Please let me know the further issues.

Comment: Thanks for the help, It seems that simply auto incrementing the column simplifies things massively but I really appreciate the help. If I had enough rep to +1 your answer I would :D